# Task Scheduler 2.0: Difference between "Stop task if..."

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

Using the Task Scheduler in Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 2012, etc...

What is the difference between this setting:

[image: Stop task if it runs longer than]

and this setting on the same task:

[image: Stop task if it runs longer than]

Does one take precedence over the other? Do they conflict?

Comment: Sounds reasonable enough here: http://superuser.com/questions/506662/what-is-the-difference-between-stop-the-task-if-it-runs-longer-than-inside-tri

Comment: @TheCleaner Agreed ... testing as we speak :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have no authoritative reference but I have just tested the behavior of multiple different `Stop` conditions in Task Scheduler on both Windows 8.1, Server 2008 R2 and 2012 R2.

### They both apply!

***Whichever stop condition is met first, stops the task.***

- **Per trigger stop condition:** The `Stop task if it runs longer than`-condition specified in the `Trigger` will only apply when the task has been invoked *by that particular trigger*.
- **Per task stop condition:** The `Stop task if it runs longer than`-condition specified for the Task (on the `Settings` tab) is global to that task, and will always apply, regardless of per-trigger stop conditions.

#### Example

Imagine a task with one trigger. If you have the per trigger stop condition set to `5 minutes`, and the per task stop condition set to `30 minutes`, you should expect the following behavior:

- Task is invoked by the trigger -> Task stops after 5 minutes.
- Task is invoked by you (via right-click and `Run`) -> Task stops after 30 minutes.

Comment: Nice job testing this!

Comment: By `stop` do you mean it does `taskkill /f /im executablename.exe` ?

Comment: @variable Well, the task scheduler doesn't invoke `taskkill.exe`, but it calls a kernel API that does the same thing as `taskkill`, yes

Comment: So is it a stop or force stop?